# How to fire an event in DatePicker when weekday clicked in javafx

Tags: javafx, datepicker

Is it possible to fire an event every time you click in week number and/or in weekday in javafx DatePicker?

I mean, I can set an actionListener to the datepicker and it will be fired when the user clicks over one specific day. But that's not what I'm looking for. I need to know when the user clicks over the name of the weekday itself, or the number of the week itself.

Is it even possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going in the right direction. This demos how to add an `onMouseClicked` event handler to the `Day of the Week` nodes. It also shows how to figure out the `CSS` for other nodes.

> Keycode:

```
for (Node node : popupContent.lookupAll(".day-name-cell")) {
    DateCell tempDateCell = (DateCell) node;
    tempDateCell.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
        System.out.println("You clicked: " + tempDateCell.getText());
    });
}
```

> Full code:

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication147 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
        DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(datePicker);
        Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();

        //To see day of the week nodes
        for (Node node : popupContent.lookupAll(".day-name-cell")) {
            node.setOnMouseClicked((event) -> {
                DateCell dateCell = (DateCell) node;
                System.out.println("You clicked: " + dateCell.getText());
            });
        }

        //To see all nodes. Used to find out how to look up certain nodes
        System.out.println("\nAll nodes:");
        for (Node node : popupContent.lookupAll("*")) {
            System.out.println("\t" + node);
        }

        StackPane root = new StackPane(popupContent);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Output:

```
All nodes:
    DatePickerContent@58c2582f[styleClass=date-picker-popup]
    BorderPane@9a2c4e3[styleClass=month-year-pane]
    HBox@6237f3e7[styleClass=spinner]
    Button@5468474f[styleClass=button left-button]''
    Label@4a04f04f[styleClass=label spinner-label]'March'
    Button@68b04c02[styleClass=button right-button]''
    HBox@6e61c6ba[styleClass=spinner]
    Button@d7d5b3e[styleClass=button left-button]''
    Label@508829bd[styleClass=label spinner-label]'2018'
    Button@3837351b[styleClass=button right-button]''
    Grid hgap=-1.0, vgap=-1.0, alignment=TOP_LEFT
    DateCell@6a1b4345[styleClass=cell date-cell day-name-cell]'Sun'
    DateCell@76997e3d[styleClass=cell date-cell day-name-cell]'Mon'
    DateCell@c263fb4[styleClass=cell date-cell day-name-cell]'Tue'
    DateCell@29bdab5e[styleClass=cell date-cell day-name-cell]'Wed'
    DateCell@190cd447[styleClass=cell date-cell day-name-cell]'Thu'
    DateCell@245929cd[styleClass=cell date-cell day-name-cell]'Fri'
    DateCell@193f696d[styleClass=cell date-cell day-name-cell]'Sat'
    DateCell@5d9cc64f[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell previous-month]'25'
    DateCell@224d9f57[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell previous-month]'26'
    DateCell@4fb7dd92[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell previous-month]'27'
    DateCell@2da1a108[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell previous-month]'28'
    DateCell@1634b44d[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'1'
    DateCell@584d26fb[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'2'
    DateCell@29e72b2d[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'3'
    DateCell@96e66f8[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'4'
    DateCell@3a4b2d44[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'5'
    DateCell@b80be08[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'6'
    DateCell@1b2e4216[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'7'
    DateCell@610dbe2d[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'8'
    DateCell@2cf9e45[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'9'
    DateCell@cb100ea[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'10'
    DateCell@65e6dd98[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'11'
    DateCell@6916ebdf[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'12'
    DateCell@17d57d0e[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'13'
    DateCell@1367994e[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'14'
    DateCell@40be8ca7[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'15'
    DateCell@1ea8cf7c[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'16'
    DateCell@2229ecaa[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'17'
    DateCell@dabac48[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'18'
    DateCell@3944c2ee[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'19'
    DateCell@614f3995[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'20'
    DateCell@c6ed5aa[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'21'
    DateCell@5cf7e183[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'22'
    DateCell@43bb1b41[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'23'
    DateCell@5ba01132[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'24'
    DateCell@21995c69[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'25'
    DateCell@42014a20[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'26'
    DateCell@597b2032[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'27'
    DateCell@20993ae[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell today selected]'28'
    DateCell@6918ed92[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'29'
    DateCell@2180eadb[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'30'
    DateCell@21fa2469[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell]'31'
    DateCell@6fa0571b[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell next-month]'1'
    DateCell@41fa4300[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell next-month]'2'
    DateCell@670abfd6[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell next-month]'3'
    DateCell@17231632[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell next-month]'4'
    DateCell@7ad68342[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell next-month]'5'
    DateCell@69273d5b[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell next-month]'6'
    DateCell@5b61dba6[styleClass=cell date-cell day-cell next-month]'7'
```

Comment: I know how to get the day of the week or weeknumber, but that is not what I'm looking for. 
I need to know when the user has pressed in some day of the week or weeknumber and know which one of them he has clicked.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. You can easily determine what was pressed by the `LocalDate` from `datePicker.getValue()`.

Comment: That info is in the output posted. You can clearly see that the user press a day of the week ->Thrusday and that the user pressed a day of the week that is in week 12?

Comment: I don't mean clicking in one specific day. I want to know when the user clicks over the name of the weekday itself. I want to know when the user presses over Monday or Tuesday or over the number 32 of the week 32.

Comment: Explain in your question better.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I'll check it as soon as possible. I don't know why you downvoted my question anyway. I updated my question.